# Change background color of Vuetify's disabled checkbox

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

[Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#states) I got example of disabled checkbox.

How can I set custom background color for "on" disabled mode and for "off" disabled mode?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic disabled tag, like this:

```js
:disabled="disabledValue"
```

Then you can add a dynamic class, like this:

```js
:class="getColourDisabled(disabledValue)"
```

with a function:

```js
getColourDisabled(disabledValue) {
  if (disabledValue) {
    return "myColourClass1"
  else {
    return "myColourClass2"
  }
}
```

With CSS classes, e.g.:

```css
.myColourClass2 {
  background-color: #dedede !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon color of the checkbox is themed by this style:

```css
.theme--light.v-input--selection-controls.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--indeterminate)
.v-icon {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.26) !important;
}
```

To theme all checkboxes, copy that selector, and apply your own `color` with `!important` to override the default theme:

```css
.theme--light.v-input--selection-controls.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--indeterminate)
.v-icon {
  color: rgba(128,5,5,.3) !important;
}
```

To theme the unchecked disabled box (the "off disabled" state) separately, add the selector for the icon name `.mdi-checkbox-blank-outline`:

```css
.theme--light.v-input--selection-controls.v-input--is-disabled:not(.v-input--indeterminate)
.v-icon.mdi-checkbox-blank-outline {
  color: rgba(20,128,100,0.4) !important;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NWvKrpY?editors=1100)